# Removing boilerplate code

Tags: android, boilerplate

I want to remove some boilerplate code from my android app. In order to do so I moved each function in a class which extends Application and made them static so that I can call them upon the class. My problem i that some functions use `startActivity()` or `getSystemService()`
and I cannot make a static reference to them. Is there any way to overcome this? What I thought is make another class and create an object each time I want to use a method but I would rather not go that way.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Context` as a parameter to these functions and call `startActivity` (and other) on this `Context` instance.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Android annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/)

Hope this helps.